# RSS Parsing using rssutil.jar is not working on Android

Tags: android, rss

I am new to Android Application development. I am trying to build a RSS Feed parser using rssutil.jar.
The piece of the code is:

```
private void ReadRSS() {
String tag = "READRSS";
try {
 //Create Parser
 RssParser parser = RssParserFactory.createDefault();

 //Parse out URL
 URL url = new URL("http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.xml");

 Rss rss = parser.parse(url);
 if(rss.getChannel() ==null)
 {
  tv.append("NULL");
  return;
 }

 Collection items = rss.getChannel().getItems();
 if(items!=null && !items.isEmpty())
 {
  for(Iterator i = items.iterator();i.hasNext();)
  {
   Item item = (Item)i.next();
   tv.append("Title:"+item.getTitle());
   tv.append("Link:" + item.getLink());
   tv.append("Description:"+item.getDescription());
  }
 }

} catch (RssParserException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 Log.v(tag, "RSSParserException");
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 Log.v(tag, "MalformedURLException");
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 Log.v(tag, "IOException");
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This code works good when executed as a java application but when I try to execute in Android phone or emulator then I get rss.getChannel() as null, can anyone please let me know why there is a difference in operation between java and android in this case? what should i do to make it work for android phone?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds quite a number of possibility would leads to problems. Especially Android Dalvik VM is very different than normal VM. What's the package dependency of the RSSParser?

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. This code does not work on 
android 2.1. Have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've forgotten to set the permission to use internet in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```